# How to not duplicate same item in a list dart?

Tags: arrays, list, button, flutter, dart

I have created a listView and button and when I click the button it adds an item to listView.

The problem is I don't want actually to repeat the same item in the list.

I've tried the .contains method but it didn't work.

I want a good solution please,

Answer (score 6):

There are different ways to achieve this:

**1)** Iterate the list and check if every element doesn't have the
   properties you consider equal:

```
items = [Item(id: 1), Item(id: 2)];
newItem = Item(id: 2);
if (items.every((item) => item.id != newItem.id)) {
  items.add(newItem);
}
```

**2)** Use `contains()` and override `== operator` (and override `hashCode` too)
   in the object class with the properties you consider equal.

```
items = [Item(id: 1), Item(id: 2)];
newItem = Item(id: 2);
if (!items.contains(newItem)) {
  items.add(newItem);
}

// inside Item class
@override
bool operator ==(other) {
  return this.id == other.id;
}

@override
int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
```

**3)** Instead of `List` use `Set`, where each element can occur only once. Its default implementation is `LinkedHashSet` that keeps track of the order.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of List, Use Set.

```
void main() {
  Set<String> currencies = {'EUR', 'USD', 'JPY'};
  currencies.add('EUR');
  currencies.add('USD');
  currencies.add('INR');
  print(currencies);
}
```

output: `{EUR, USD, JPY, INR} // unique items only`

Reference: [Set<E> class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Set-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the List already contains the element before you add it:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html

```
if(!List.contains(element) { add }
```

The `contains` method checks for equality, not for reference, so it must work as long as you compare a similar element. If your code isn't working, please provide it to us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your list contains custom objects you may need to override the [equality operator](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) in the custom class.

You could also use a [Set](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-core/Set-class.html) instead of a List.